# Creating File object from file in tomcat WEB-INF

Tags: java

This code runs fine:

```
File file = new File("C:\\workspaces\\myProject\\Classloadertest\\WebContent\\WEB-INF\\lib\\Myclass.jar");
```

however with this being a Tomcat web project, how do I load the jar file using a relative path instead of the absolute path?

I have tried altering the following with no luck:

```
File file = new File("\\WEB-INF\\lib\\Myclass.jar");
```

Comment: You don't. You load it as a resource, or you use `ServletContext.getRealpath()`.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne  That was was I was looking for!